# entity framework self reference foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to create a simple self reference in entity framework 5 code first. An item can have an optional child and does not need to know about its parent.

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int? PreviousItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual Item PreviousItem { get; set; }
}
```

However it does not want to use my key field for some reason because I end up with these three:

```
ItemId
PreviousItemId
PreviousItem_ItemId
```

I want it to use the field I specified and not that extra one at the end. I've tried an annotation:

```
[ForeignKey("PreviousItemId")]
public virtual Item PreviousItem { get; set; }
```

and also with fluent api:

```
public class ItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public ItemConfiguration()
    {
        HasOptional(i => i.PreviousItem)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.PreviousItemId);
    }
}
```

But I receive this exception with both of them:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.GetQualifiedTableName(XDocument model, String entitySetName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<FindRenamedIndependentAssociationColumns>b__ba(<>f__AnonymousType16`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifieraa)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Sequence contains no elements
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for reading. The exception occurs when I run update-database from the package manager console.

Comment: Is this a migration that upgrades an existing database?

Comment: Could you please show us both `Models` instead of just the one shown?

Comment: Works for me if I create a new database, hence my previous question.

Comment: There's only one model, the previous item is the same as the one shown.

I tried creating a new project and sure enough it did work. Looking at the exception I see it involves migration stuff so I dropped every table in the db and then did the migration and sure enough it worked. So I have no idea what caused it...